# How to receive messages from ActiveMQ with JMSTemplate and a selector?

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic

I'm trying to grab messages on a persistent activemq queue.

If I call

```
jmsTemplate.receive("queue.response")
```

I get a message. However if I call

```
jmsTemplate.receiveSelected("queue.response", "JMSCorrelationId='1854044'")
```

I time out while waiting.

I'm looking at the queue using the ActiveMQ web console and I can see that the messages are there ready to be consumed. The correlation ids are visible in the console and I can also see them in the messages I receive with the straight receive("queue..") call.

Presumably I'm doing something wrong with my actual selector, but every example I can find looks like what I've got.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try without ' around Id value?

Comment: Are you sure that your correlation id is correct ?

Comment: @Carlo : Yeah, tried without the '. The result is that it picks up all messages, I presume because the selector is invalid.

Comment: @Nico : Yep, double triple and quadruple checked the correlation id. I'm copying it straight from the webconsole and into my code.

Comment: Did you set the correlation id (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/jms/Message.html#setJMSCorrelationID(java.lang.String)) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Facepalm! JMSCorrelationID is case sensitive. I was trying to use JMSCorrelationId...